# How to compare Laravel's url()->previous() with url()->current()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, string-comparison

It seems Laravel's `url()->previous()` and `url()->current()` is broken.
I can't do a `if previous == current`, because `previous` outputs with http:/https: and ends with `/`, and `current` outputs without this.

I thought this was not going to be a problem. I could just prepend `http:`/`https:` to the `url()->current()` and move on with my life, but apparently it was not going to be that simple.

**The problem:** $url_1 != $url_2

Code:

```
$url_1 = url()->previous();
$url_2 = url()->current();

var_dump( $url_1 );
var_dump( $url_2 );
```

Output:

```
string(22) "http://localhost:3000/"
string(21) "//localhost:3000"
```

**Attempt to fix:**

Code:

```
$url_1 = url()->previous();
$url_2 = 'http:' . url()->current() . '/';

var_dump( $url_1 );
var_dump( $url_2 );
```

Output:

```
string(22) "http://localhost:3000/" 
string(27) "http://localhost:3000/"
```

So `$url_1` is still not equal to `$url_2`. Does anyone know what's going on here? Seems to me that `http:` is being treated as a single character.

How can I actually compare the two, because as it is now, `$url_1` is never going to be equal to `$url_2`...

Comment: I just tried dumping `url()->previous()` and `url()->current()` in a view (and changed URLs a couple of times) and it outputs exactly same format for me. The format includes `http://`, and doesn't end with `/`

Comment: @devk Seems to happen with me when I open the page in a new tab. However, if I click a link going to the same page, `url()->previous()` gets `http:` in front.

Comment: I believe you have some encoding issues, so let's try to convert all vars to utf8, before comparing. If that passes then you probably have some serious problems with encoding in your project files...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that `previous()` in `Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator` uses `getPreviousUrlFromSession()` which returns the result of this: `session()->previousUrl()`.

Comparing `session()->previousUrl()` with `url()->current()` actually works. Though I'm still curious as to why the first method doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can trap a redirect loop by checking the current url with the previous url one.

```
$redirect = app('redirect');

if (request()->fullUrl() != $redirect->back()->getTargetUrl()){
    $response = $redirect->back();
} else {
    $response = $redirect->to('/');
} 

return $response
    ->withInput($request->except($this->dontFlash))
    ->withErrors('That page could not be found. Please try again or report the broken link: ' . $request->getRequestUri());
```